# L = {T | T is a turing machine that recognizes {00, 01}} Prove L is undecidable

Tags: turing-machines, reduction, decidable

L = {<T> | T is a turing machine that recognizes {00, 01}}

Prove L is undecidable.

I am really having difficulties even understanding the reduction to use here.

I'm not asking for free lunch, just a push in the right direction.

Comment: This might be better off on math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Actually it would be better off at theoretical CS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A direct application of Rice's theorem will let you prove this without doing any work at all.

Some Turing machines recognize {00, 01}. Some don't. The difference is semantic in that it has to do with the strings accepted, not the structure of the automaton. Hence, by Rice's theorem, this set is undecidable.